# Passing value from JSON http.get to scope.value using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am currently writing a code that is displaying the file from json to a charting JS.

```
var app = angular.module('cpu-usage', []);
app.controller('GaugeController', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http) {

    var viewAll = this;
    viewAll.gauge = [];
    $http.get('dom/json/cpuUsage.json').success(function(data){
        viewAll.gauge = data;
    });

    $scope.value = viewAll.gauge[0].value;
```

However, I am having a hard time taking out the value from my variable array viewAll.gauge. I'm having an error in:

```
Error: viewAll.gauge[0] is undefined
@http://localhost:8080/js/directives/cpusagegauge.js:11:2
e@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:35:343
h/<.instantiate@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:35:474
ce/this.$get</<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:68:140
x/<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:54:226
q@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:7:384
x@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:54:89
g@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:48:28
g@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:48:1
g@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:48:1
x@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:55:10
g@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:48:28
x@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:55:10
z/<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:61:261
l/k.success/<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:73:32
Re/e/m.promise.then/L@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:99:147
Re/e/m.promise.then/L@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:99:147
Re/f/<.then/<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:100:321
me/this.$get</g.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:111:1
me/this.$get</g.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:108:458
me/this.$get</g.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:112:323
g@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:73:285
x@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:77:322
Ne/</y.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:78:358

http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js
Line 93
```

BTW, my JSON file is pretty small.

```
[{
"value": "80"
}]
```

Comment: Why downvote the question? It contains all relevant informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the callback of `$http.get()` is called asynchronously. In your case `viewAll.gauge = data;`is called *after* `$scope.value = viewAll.gauge[0].value;`

The following should work:

```
var app = angular.module('cpu-usage', []);
app.controller('GaugeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

    var viewAll = this;
    viewAll.gauge = [];
    $http.get('dom/json/cpuUsage.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.value = data.gauge[0].value;
    });
})
```

Additionally if you want to update scope variables in async callbacks you have to wrap it in `$scope.$apply(function() { //your code goes here });`. Here is the full example:

```
var app = angular.module('cpu-usage', []);
app.controller('GaugeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

    var viewAll = this;
    viewAll.gauge = [];
    $http.get('dom/json/cpuUsage.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.apply(function() {
            $scope.value = data.gauge[0].value;
        });
    });
})
```